# How to prevent temp files from being created in PHP when receiving binary files

Tags: php, stream, binary-data, temporary-files, memory-limit

I'm trying to create a small service that is able to receive a file and resend to another location without creating a physical copy in any way (for security reasons).
I'm sending the file with a POST request as raw binary data and accessing it with `file_get_contents('php://input')`

simplified code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://totally-legit-url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRASNFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: text/plain']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('php://input'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem I'm however encountering is that whenever I send a file, even small files (I tried many file sizes like for instance 2KB, 299KB and 8MB), PHP automatically creates a temporary file in the `sys_temp_dir` directory which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent. I've been searching everywhere for an answer but I have not found a way to prevent PHP from creating a temporary file. I've even tried setting the `sys_temp_dir` to `/dev/null` but then the script just crashed with an error.

The script is running on Apache 2.4.25 in PHP 7.1.3

Is there a way to force the server to not create temp files and work with memory only?

Comment: look up php proxy

Comment: You are missing the stream context. file_get_contents() can work with streams. FYI: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php